# How to filter on date in subquery outside of subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

My ETL query returns some info about an employee and also has two aggregated columns (`ActualCount` and `ExpectedCount`)which come from a subquery.

The issue I was having was that the table the subquery is left-joined on is updated independently of the aggregated info. So when I had my query running incrementally, the query would see that the t1.ModifiedDate hadn't been updated and wouldn't return new count records even though the count records had been updated.

I wrote this query which returns the desired result for an incremental load but my issue now is that during an initial load there are multiple results returned for each ID and it violates the PK constraint. This is due to the `t2.ModifiedDate` column I added in the subquery, which I need to filter by.

Is there a way to get the t2.ModifiedDate and bring it out to the main query without producing duplicates?

**Desired Result (I added one result for this incremental test):**

[image]

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT  t1.EmployeeGoalID ,
        t1.EmployeeID ,
        t1.EmployeeMonthlyGoal ,
        t1.TargetMonth ,
        t1.TargetYear ,
        Actuals.BranchID ,
        Actuals.ActualCount ,
        CASE WHEN Actuals.ActualCount IS NULL THEN 0
             WHEN Actuals.ActualCount < t1.EmployeeMonthlyGoal
             THEN Actuals.ActualCount
             ELSE t1.EmployeeMonthlyGoal
        END AS ExpectedCount ,
        t1.CreateDate ,
        t1.ModifiedDate ,
        t1.Deleted
FROM    dbo.EmployeeGoal t1
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT t2.InspectionSubmissionResultID) AS ActualCount ,
                            t2.BranchID ,
                            t3.EmployeeID ,
                            MONTH(DATEADD(hh, -5, t2.SubmissionDate)) AS ActualMonth ,
                            YEAR(DATEADD(hh, -5, t2.SubmissionDate)) AS ActualYear,
                            t2.ModifiedDate -- <<<<<This causes the problem
                    FROM    InspectionSubmissionResult t2
                            INNER JOIN dbo.InspectionSubmissionEmployee t3 ON t3.InspectionSubmissionResultID = t2.InspectionSubmissionResultID
                    WHERE   t3.InspectorType = 'INSP'
                    GROUP BY t2.BranchID ,
                            t3.EmployeeID ,
                            MONTH(DATEADD(hh, -5, t2.SubmissionDate)) ,
                            YEAR(DATEADD(hh, -5, t2.SubmissionDate)) ,
                            t2.ModifiedDate  -- <<<<This causes the problem
                  ) AS Actuals ON Actuals.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
                                  AND t1.TargetMonth = Actuals.ActualMonth
                                  AND t1.TargetYear = Actuals.ActualYear
WHERE Actuals.ModifiedDate > '1/23/2017' OR t1.ModifiedDate > '1/23/2017'
-- I need this Actuals.ModifiedDate
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: As for your actual question we need a bit more information to be able to offer much help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Your comment is "this causes the problem". What is the problem?

Comment: I am assuming that the `InspectionSubmissionResult` table can have multiple rows for each combination of BranchID and (month, year of) SubmissionDate. You can correct your problem by SELECTing `MAX(t2.ModifiedDate) AS ModifiedDate`, instead of grouping by that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of carrying the `ModifiedDate` up from the subquery to use it in your `where` clause, you can instead use [**`exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx).

Here is your query with the change, and some reformatting:

```
select
      eg.EmployeeGoalID
    , eg.EmployeeID
    , eg.EmployeeMonthlyGoal
    , eg.TargetMonth
    , eg.TargetYear
    , a.BranchID
    , a.ActualCount
    , ExpectedCount = case 
        when a.ActualCount is null then 0 
        when a.ActualCount < eg.EmployeeMonthlyGoal then a.ActualCount 
        else eg.EmployeeMonthlyGoal 
        end 
    , eg.CreateDate
    , eg.ModifiedDate
    , eg.Deleted
from dbo.EmployeeGoal eg
  left join (
   select 
        ActualCount = count(distinct isr.InspectionSubmissionResultID) 
      , isr.BranchID
      , ise.EmployeeID
      , ActualMonth = month(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate)) 
      , ActualYear  = year(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate)) 
      --, isr.ModifiedDate -- <<<<<This causes the problem 
   from dbo.InspectionSubmissionResult isr
    inner join dbo.InspectionSubmissionEmployee ise 
      on ise.InspectionSubmissionResultID = isr.InspectionSubmissionResultID
   where ise.InspectorType = 'insp'
   group by 
        isr.BranchID
      , ise.EmployeeID
      , month(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate))
      , year(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate))
      --, isr.ModifiedDate -- <<<<This causes the problem
   ) as a 
       on a.EmployeeID = eg.EmployeeID 
      and eg.TargetMonth = a.ActualMonth 
      and eg.TargetYear = a.ActualYear
  where eg.ModifiedDate > '1/23/2017'
    -- or a.ModifiedDate > '1/23/2017'
    or exists (
      select 1 
        from dbo.InspectionSubmissionResult isr 
          inner join  dbo.InspectionSubmissionEmployee ise 
            on ise.InspectionSubmissionResultID 
              = isr.InspectionSubmissionResultID
        where ise.EmployeeId = eg.EmployeeId
          and isr.ModifiedDate > '1/23/2017'
          and month(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate))=eg.TargetMonth
          and year(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate))=eg.TargetYear
        )
```

The `max(isr.ModifiedDate)` method suggested by Laughing Vergil would probably be better.

```
select
      eg.EmployeeGoalID
    , eg.EmployeeID
    , eg.EmployeeMonthlyGoal
    , eg.TargetMonth
    , eg.TargetYear
    , a.BranchID
    , a.ActualCount
    , ExpectedCount = case 
        when a.ActualCount is null then 0 
        when a.ActualCount < eg.EmployeeMonthlyGoal then a.ActualCount 
        else eg.EmployeeMonthlyGoal 
        end 
    , eg.CreateDate
    , eg.ModifiedDate
    , eg.Deleted
from dbo.EmployeeGoal eg
  left join (
   select 
        ActualCount = count(distinct isr.InspectionSubmissionResultID) 
      , isr.BranchID
      , ise.EmployeeID
      , ActualMonth = month(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate)) 
      , ActualYear  = year(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate)) 
      , ModifiedDate = max(isr.ModifiedDate) -- <<<<<This causes the problem 
   from dbo.InspectionSubmissionResult isr
    inner join dbo.InspectionSubmissionEmployee ise 
      on ise.InspectionSubmissionResultID = isr.InspectionSubmissionResultID
   where ise.InspectorType = 'insp'
   group by 
        isr.BranchID
      , ise.EmployeeID
      , month(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate))
      , year(dateadd(hh, - 5, isr.SubmissionDate))
      --, isr.ModifiedDate -- <<<<This causes the problem
   ) as a 
       on a.EmployeeID = eg.EmployeeID 
      and eg.TargetMonth = a.ActualMonth 
      and eg.TargetYear = a.ActualYear
  where eg.ModifiedDate > '1/23/2017'
     or a.ModifiedDate > '1/23/2017'
```

Comment: The isr table doesn't have an `EmployeeID` so I joined it on the ise table in the or exists clause but now it's returning rows from all of the years. I'll update my question to show the changes.

Comment: updated the `exists()` to include the join to get the `EmployeeID` from `InspectionSubmissionEmployee ` -- If you only need the aggregate data for each month if that month's data has been modified > x, why not add that to the `where` in subquery `a`?

Comment: That's what I did as well but it's returning all previous years for the one employee whos info was updated as opposed to one row which is expected

Comment: If I add the where to the subquery, the data won't be pulled because the EmployeeGoal date also has a where and that date is older therefore the data from the subquery won't get pulled into the main query

Comment: Gotcha. Updated the `exists()` to include the `where month&year =...` but Laughing Vergil's suggestion of `max()` is a simpler answer

Comment: Only yours worked in my specific case. Thank you for the help!